# How to disable a TestNG listener dynamically based on the testng suite invoked

Tags: java, testng

I have three testng xml files with names test1.xml,test2.xml and test3.xml.Each file is having their own testng suites.I am invoking test2.xml and test3.xml in test1.xml .In test1.xml I configured a listener and I want this listener to be disable when the suite in test2.xml is invoked.I did not find any thing related to this in Testng java doc.Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, it is not possible to do what you want easily because a TestNG instance shares listeners between all suite-files: https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/main/java/org/testng/TestNG.java#L1253

But I think it could be considered as an issue (or at least a evident improvment).
You should fill an issue on Github: https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues

A possible work-arround would be to create yourself 3 testng instances with one diffrent suite-file by instance.